# Sort by group's max date, but keeping the groups together

Tags: c#, sql, db2

Let's say I'm a Pokemon Trainer with IBM DB2 as the database.  I'm not organized and threw all of my Pokemon on the table.  Some of the Pokemon, I don't remember which backpack they came from.  I have a log, so that helps the backpack issue.

On the table

```
Backpack Number Pokemon #   Name        DateCaught
2               1           Charmander  8/5/2016
3               2           Rattata     8/4/2016
3               3           Rattata     8/5/2016
                4           Pidgey      8/6/2016
                5           Pidgey      8/1/2016
4               6           Ekans       8/6/2016
```

What we wrote down

```
Backpack Number Action  Pokemon #   Timestamp
2               Caught  1           8/5/2016
1               Caught  3           8/5/2016
                Seen    4           8/1/2016
1               Caught  4           8/6/2016
                Seen    5           7/30/2016
1               Caught  5           8/1/2016
```

I want to sort by backpack with the oldest Pokemon, but keep the Pokemon grouped together.

```
Backpack Number Pokemon #   Name        DateCaught
1               5           Pidgey      8/1/2016
1               4           Pidgey      8/6/2016
3               2           Rattata     8/4/2016
3               3           Rattata     8/5/2016
2               1           Charmander  8/5/2016
4               6           Ekans       8/6/2016
```

I already have the query.  I just need to figure out how to sort it like the above.  I'm also using pagination so that I have to grab a certain range.

```
SELECT main.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN On_The_Table.Backpack_Number IS NOT NULL THEN On_The_Table.Backpack_Number ELSE Logs.Backpack_Number END AS Backpack_Number
        , On_The_Table.Pokemon_Number
        , On_The_Table.Name
        , On_The_Table.DateCaught
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS RANK

    FROM On_The_Table

  LEFT JOIN 
  (
      SELECT DISTINCT
            Backpack_Number,
            Pokemon_Number,
            DateCaught
        FROM What_We_Wrote_Down
        WHERE Backpack_Number IS NOT NULL AND Action = 'Caught'
  ) Logs
 ON On_The_Table.Pokemon_Number = Logs.Pokemon_Number AND On_The_Table.Date_Caught = Logs.Date_Caught


) main
WHERE RANK >= @searchParm1 AND RANK <= @searchParm2
```

Comment: In your inner query, why not calculate `MIN(DateCaught) OVER (PARTITION BY Backpack_Name)   AS Backpack_MinDateCaught` as an additional field, and then `ORDER BY Backpack_MinDateCaught, Backpack_Name`, etc?

Comment: For some reason, I'm having trouble doing that.  I'm getting an error _Token ( was not valid._

Comment: Best give the exact SQL you're using with the exact error message.  It appears you just have a `(` in the wrong place, or a missing `)` or maybe a missing `)`.  But without the exact SQL we'll be guessing forever.

Comment: Right.  I'm just trying to run a very simple line to get to the bottom of this error.  `SELECT SUM(moneyColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY anotherColumn) AS MINDATE FROM MYTABLE` I've looked in the IBM document and it does support OLAP Specifications...  The highlighted token is the `(` next to `PARTITION`

Comment: Put a space between `OVER` and `(`

Comment: Tried that too.  Didn't work.

Comment: @Emwat You need to post SQL that actually works.  Your column names don't match the example data, nor will the SQL statement you provide even return the result set you're saying you want.

Comment: @Emwat That said, just adding `ORDER BY Backpack_Name, Name, DateCaught` to your table expression (the subquery you're referring to with the correlation name `main`) will likely provide what you're looking for.